Функция WSASend и протокол UDP
Функция WSASend в Windows принимает на вход несколько буферов. Но возник вопрос: если используется протокол типа UDP, то все эти буферы будут склеены и отправлены как один или каждый будет отправлен в виде отдельного сообщения?..
В документации ничего на эту тему не нашёл, кроме:

Для сокетов, ориентированных на сообщения, необходимо соблюдать
осторожность, чтобы не превышать максимальный размер сообщения
базового транспорта, который можно получить, получив значение
параметра сокета SO_MAX_MSG_SIZE. Если данные слишком длинные для
атомарной передачи через базовый протокол, возвращается ошибка
WSAEMSGSIZE и данные не передаются.

Но тут непонятно, относится это предупреждение к данным в одном буфере или во всех суммарно...

Здесь речь идёт об одном из 16-ти возможных буферов - это можно проверить на практике, определив всего 1 буфер и увеличивая данные в нём до появления ошибки WSAEMSGSIZE. Некоторую инфу о текущих провайдерах можно получить в консоли по netsh winsock show catalog - так можно будет узнать версию, размеры структур и прочее.
